# why form control is showing [Object][Object] in reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have `functions` which create `reactive` form dynamically. I just have to pass `array` of `feilds`.

here are the functions inside my `service`

```
createForm(fieldsArr: any[]) {
  let formObject = {};
  fieldsArr.forEach(f => {
    if(f.isArray){
      if(f.defaultValue === null){
          formObject[f.name] = this.fb.array([]);
      } else {
          formObject[f.name] = this.fb.array([this.createArrayType(f.nestedFieldsArr)]);
        }
      } else {
          formObject[f.name] = [f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '', f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator];
    }
  })
  return this.fb.group(formObject);
}


createArrayType(nestedFieldsArr: any[]) {
   let nestedFormObj = {};
   nestedFieldsArr.forEach(f => {
    nestedFormObj[f.name] = [[{ value: f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '', disabled: f.isDisabled ? true : false }], f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator]
   })
   let form = this.fb.group(nestedFormObj);
   return form;
}
```

This is `array` of `fields` which i am passing to my `function` to create `reactive-form`

```
public marketPlaceFormFields = [
{
  name: 'pickupLocations',
  isRequired: true,
  isArray: true,
  nestedFieldsArr: [
    {
      name: 'location',
      isRequired: true
    },
    {
      name: 'lat',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'long',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'locationCode',
      isRequired: false,
    },
    {
      name: 'dateTime',
      isRequired: true
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: 'deliveryLocations',
  isRequired: true,
  isArray: true,
  nestedFieldsArr: [
    {
      name: 'location',
      isRequired: true
    },
    {
      name: 'lat',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'long',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'locationCode',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'dateTime',
      isRequired: true
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: 'waypoints',
  isRequired: true,
  isArray: true,
  defaultValue: null,
  nestedFieldsArr: [
    {
      name: 'location',
      isRequired: true
    },
    {
      name: 'lat',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'long',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'locationCode',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'type',
      isRequired: false
    },
    {
      name: 'dateTime',
      isRequired: true
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: 'bidVehicles',
  isRequired: true,
  isArray: true,
  nestedFieldsArr: [
    {
      name: 'vehicleLoadId',
      isRequired: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'categoryId',
      isRequired: true
    },
    {
      name: 'numberOfVehicles',
      isRequired: true
    },
    {
      name: 'loadRequirementId',
      isRequired: false,
      defaultValue: 1
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: 'shipmentWeight',
  isRequired: true
},
{
  name: 'budgetMin',
  isRequired: true
},
{
  name: 'budgetMax',
  isRequired: true
},
{
  name: 'paymentTerm',
  isRequired: false,
  defaultValue: 'Cash on Delivery'
},
{
  name: 'bidDateFrom',
  isRequired: true
},
{
  name: 'bidDateTo',
  isRequired: true
},
{
  name: 'orderId',
  isRequired: false
},
{
  name: 'insertedBy',
  isRequired: false
},
{
  name: 'shipperId',
  isRequired: false
}
];
```

`component.ts`

```
get pickLocatons() { return this.frm.pickupLocations as FormArray; }

ngOnInit(){
   this.marketForm = this.us.createForm(this.constants.marketPlaceFormFields);
}
```

`component.html`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pickControl of pickLocatons.controls; let i = index">
<div class="row" [formGroup]="pickControl">
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>
        Pick up Location
        <span class="text-danger font-bold ml-1">*</span>
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle ml-1 color-primary cursor-pointer" placement="auto"
           ngbPopover="{{constants.popovers.bid.pickup}}" popoverClass="op-popover"></i>
        </label>
        <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bazar Kharadan, Koh..." formControlName="location" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' :  pickControl.get('location')?.errors &&
              (pickControl.get('location').touched ||  pickControl.get('location').dirty)}" />
           <div class="input-group-append cursor-pointer" (click)="openMapModal('pickupLoc', i)">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-map-marker px-1"></i></span>
           </div>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="pickControl.get('location')?.errors &&
           (pickControl.get('location').touched || pickControl.get('location').dirty)">
        <span *ngIf="pickControl.get('location')?.errors?.required" class="text-danger">
        {{constants.errors.required.location}}
        </span>
        </span>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>
           <!-- <i class="fa fa-map-marker color-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
           Add Corresponding Code
           <i class="fa fa-info-circle ml-1 color-primary cursor-pointer" placement="auto"
              ngbPopover="{{constants.popovers.bid.code}}" popoverClass="op-popover"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Code" formControlName="locationCode" />
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>
           <!-- <i class="fa fa-calendar-o color-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i>  -->
           Date/Time
           <span class="text-danger font-bold ml-1">*</span>
           <i class="fa fa-info-circle ml-1 color-primary cursor-pointer" placement="auto"
              ngbPopover="{{constants.popovers.bid.picDate}}" popoverClass="op-popover"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" formControlName="dateTime" min="{{ (minDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 'T00:00' }}" [max]="eConfig.DATETIME_MAX" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' :  pickControl.get('dateTime')?.errors &&
        (pickControl.get('dateTime').touched ||  pickControl.get('dateTime').dirty)}">
        <span class="help-block" *ngIf="pickControl.get('dateTime')?.errors &&
           (pickControl.get('dateTime').touched || pickControl.get('dateTime').dirty)">
        <span *ngIf="pickControl.get('dateTime')?.errors?.required" class="text-danger">
        This is required
        </span>
        </span>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 mt-28" (click)="addLocation()" *ngIf="i === 0">+ Add Stop</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 mt-28" (click)="removeLocation(i)" *ngIf="i > 0">+ Remove</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

but the problem is that when page loads so form array fields are displaying [object][object] as value of inputs like this

[image]

I don't know why form fields are displaying `[object][object]` after page loads

**Note: I only included necessary code in the post.**

Comment: Because you set a FormArray inside a single input... You have to loop over your formArray to set 1 input per item of the formArray....

Comment: but if you see my `ng-container` so i am looping through my `formArray` and binding a single formgroup's control to input.

Comment: Your form init is very messy... you should use if/else instead of nested evil ternary code. From what I see, you inject a FormGroup (returned by `createArrayType`) in your FormArray. Your FormArray should contain FormControls, not FormGroups, from what I understand from your code...

Comment: can you give proper answer to this question by manipulating little bit of code??

Comment: Can you first transform your ternary code into if/else statements please ?

Comment: @Random i refactored my code. Please check updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a FormGroup, which contains a FormArray, which contains a list containing 1 FormGroup, containing your FormControls. In the HTML, you are expecting a FormGroup, containing a FormArray, containing a list of FormControls. So it looks like you nested it too much, or don't decaplusated enough in the HTML. From your comments, it looks like you need the FormArray, so here is an updated solution:

```
createForm(fieldsArr: any[]) {
  const formGroup = new FormGroup({});
  fieldsArr.forEach(f => {
    if(f.isArray){
      if(f.defaultValue === null){
          // seems to never happen ? because you would need 1 default value for each element of your array, not just one defaultValue.
          // formObject[f.name] = this.fb.array([]);
      } else {
          formGroup.addControl(f.name, this.createNestedFormArray(f.nestedFieldsArr)); // removed the FormArray layer
      }
    } else {
      const formControl = new FormControl(f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '',
                                              f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator);
      formGroup.addControl(f.name, formControl);
      // formObject[f.name] = [f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '', f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator];
    }
  });
  return formGroup;
}


createNestedFormArray(nestedFieldsArr: any[]) {
   const nestedFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
   nestedFieldsArr.forEach(f => {
     const formControl = new FormControl(f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '',
                                              f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator);
     if ( f.isDisabled ) {
       formControl.disable();  // moved disabled logic from constructor (not valid)
     }
     nestedFormGroup.addControl(f.name, formControl);
     // nestedFormObj[f.name] = [[{ value: f.defaultValue ? f.defaultValue : '', disabled: f.isDisabled ? true : false }], f.isRequired ? Validators.required : Validators.nullValidator]
   })
   return new FormArray([nestedFormGroup]);
}
```

And in the HTML, loop over the FormArray:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pickArray of pickLocatons.controls">
  <!-- pickArray is the FormArray, containing multiple FormGroups -->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let pickNestedGroup of pickArray; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <!-- pickNestedGroup is the FormGroup, containing multiple FormControls (location, lat, long...) -->
    <!-- [formGroupName]="i" means you are using the ith element of the FormArray as reference for every following formControlNames, instead of the parent one -->
    <input formControlName="location"/>
```

Comment: but i want multiple form groups of pickup and delivery locations. because user can add multiple pickup and delivery locations.

Comment: Ok, so you init the FormArray with a single element, but then, user can add one, right ? So you have to loop over the FormArray in the HTML, I'll update answer

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me. I modified your code a little bit according to my need :)